# Why don't my textures distort linearly when I "square up" my UV map?

Tags: uv, texture-coordinates

I wanted to create a light up dance floor texture for a part of a model that is flat on the Z axis, but fills out in a hexagonal arch shape in the X, and Y direction. Originally, I was going to draw all my angled lines in a photo editing program, then make a bunch of squares and then round their corners, but then I got an idea and thought it would be way faster to just square up my UV's in blender, make a regular grid with rounded squares in a photo editing program, and then let the natural linear interpolation/distortion/stretching of this square onto the face of my object fit my grid to my object.

What I seem to have discovered is that this face isn't linearly fit/distorted to my object at all. What is actually happening here and why and is there a way to get linear interpolation?

Here's the shape of my flat faces:
[image]

Here's my texture mapped to my UV grid shape:
[image]

And here's what I'm seeing in my viewport in the shading view:
[image]

Why am I seeing this weird jagged distortion instead of a bunch of linear straight lines projected from one edge of my face outward to the other edge of my face? Is there a way to fix this and have it render what I would consider "properly"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The distortion is caused by the fact that a quad is always made of 2 tris, therefore this triangulation that distorts the texture. I don't think that there's any other way than subdividing your mesh to reduce this effect, or give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: "I don't think that there's any other way than subdividing your mesh to reduce this effect." -- Basically, yeah, but one option is, don't use distorted UV, and the other is, use a texture image that takes your triangulation into account.  In this case, the latter would probably be a selected-to-active bake from a heavily subdivided copy.

Comment: So maybe give your answer, I'm curious to know what you mean by "use a texture image that takes your triangulation into account"

Comment: The bake I mentioned would provide an image that took the triangulation into account.

Comment: oh ok yes, a bit tedious though